# JavaCC line number in exception

Tags: javacc

i use JavaCC for parsing my script...
I have something like this in my *.jj

```
private Type parseType() throws MyScriptException:
{
    Token token;
}
{   (   token = <INT>
    |   token = <FLOAT>
    |   token = <BOOL>
    |   token = <STRING>
   )
    { return types.get(token.image); }
}
```

in `types.get` I throw an exception from type `MyScriptException` when anything goes wrong.
But I need in the output from which line the error was caused.
Can I integrate the line from error in `MyScriptException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Token` class has attributes that give the location of the token:

```
  /** The line number of the first character of this Token. */
  public int beginLine;
  /** The column number of the first character of this Token. */
  public int beginColumn;
  /** The line number of the last character of this Token. */
  public int endLine;
  /** The column number of the last character of this Token. */
  public int endColumn;
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but in my script there are include statements, which I parsed too.
These include statements contains other files, which are parsed here. How to access to the token of these files.

Comment: @steven that's more tricky. How do you include them?

Comment: pls see here, the question above is answered already
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71396664/javacc-line-number-in-exception-for-included-files

Comment: The question will be how can I access the token
 `<INCLUDE> filename = parseString()` in jj file which generates such like this 
`jj_consume_token(INCLUDE);` in a generated file.